# BITCOINJ: how to make my wallet aware again about change of my transaction status after my server restart?

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoinj

Using bitcoinj, my server created a transaction and it was broadcasted on the blockchain. I can get its history using: walletAppKit.wallet().getTransaction(txHash)

It is in Pending state.

Then I stopped my server before the transaction get confirmed.

Then I started the server again, and I was still getting Pending status when calling walletAppKit.wallet().getTransaction(txHash), although the status is well confirmed on explorer like https://live.blockcypher.com/

I understand that when server was down, there was no more listener for change events on that wallet/transaction. But the question is how make my wallet aware again about the new change of my transaction status after my server restart?

(I am on TestNet by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Try synchronizing your wallet again, you can delete the file ***.spvchain***

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are most likely not connected to enough peers to download the chain since you last synced. Sometimes in bitcoinj peer discovery takes a while. I recommend giving it a few more tries.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `WalletAppKit` is resyncing with the network after the server restarts.  After the wallet is back online, you can explicitly query the transaction status using the transaction hash.
Review the logs from your `WalletAppKit` for any messages related to syncing and transaction events.
And ensure that your server has a stable and active connection to the TestNet.